# How do I make an icon POST/PUT?

Tags: html

`<input type=image ...>` is not the way to go because it submits the x,y coordinates.

When I click on an icon, I want to submit as `POST` or `PUT`, so there should be some `form, input` actions.

```
<form action="" method="PUT" name="abc_table_form">
   display icons

</form>
```

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks.

---

```
<table>
  <row1> <form action="http://google.com/123/"> <button> icon1 </button></form> </row1>
  <row2> <form action="http://google.com/456/"> <button> icon1 </button></form> </row2>
</table>
```

The form adds extra space to the table. It looks ugly. The action in the form is different, and I believe `<button>` here is based on the action of `form`. What is the right way to deal with this?

Comment: why don't you use standard html form `<form method="put">...</form>`?

Comment: @haynar What's the standard html form? I have a form wrapped around the icons. Is that what you are asking? I think I included it after u came here. My bad. Yes I have that.

Comment: @haynar — That isn't standard.

Comment: I don't think there is a right or wrong way .. it depends on what you want to achieve. Would you prefer a javascript option or strictly HTML ??

Comment: @Baba I prefer strictly HTML, but if you can present both it would be nice. I think for JS I have to listen to the form id / class, and then submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms [only support POST and GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-method).

An image input will submit a POST form (although since they are designed to be used as a server side image map, they aren't really appropriate unless you want to submit the coordinates on the image).

`<button type="submit"> <img src="..." alt="Submit"> </button>` is the more semantic way to submit the form using an image (although some versions of Internet Explorer will submit an odd value in response to this).

If you want to make HTTP requests using other methods (i.e. PUT) from a browser then you need to use XMLHttpRequest and construct it using JavaScript. Browser support for this is a bit variable.

Comment: Thank you. `POST` creates resources. Regardless, the form is wrapping a table. Each row has the same set of icons, except the parameters are different (this is a dynamic web app). Is the button submission based on `form action='xxxxxx'` ?? Thanks. or should I wrap a form for each row? since each row takes different paraemters.

Comment: A form can contain an entire table. A form can be contained in a single cell. You cannot have a form that wraps a single row of a table. Use the [name of the button](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html) to distinguish which row you care about in a cross-browser fashion.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
 <tr><td> <form action="..." method=POST><button><img src=test.png alt=Test></button>
    <input type=hidden name=foo value=bar></form> 
 <tr> ...
</table>
```

That is, wrap each image in a button and wrap the button in a form of its own. Even if the forms all have the same `action` attribute, you need separate forms to pass different data (different values for the parameter `foo` in the example) in a robust pure-HTML way. The reason is that you do this using hidden fields, and they relate to the enclosing form.

For styling, consider these:

form { display: inline; }
   button { border: none; padding: 0; }

They will make the images appear as such, with no hint of their being clickable, so you should probably explain in prose on the page what they do.

You cannot make a form wrap a table row (except of course if it’s a one-row table). You would just have to include the various parameters separately inside each form (there’s no problem in having identical `input type=hidden` elements inside different forms). It’s dull, but you’re probably generating the page programmatically anyway, and programs love to do dull things.

Comment: Thank you! I assume it's `display` that's making it "seen unclickable` right? Is there a way to make it look clickable?

Comment: @CppLearner, no, `display: inline` is meant to remove extra spacing around the form appearing in some (mostly old) browsers. Setting `border: none` removes the default border around the button, and `padding: 0` removes the default gray padding. If you remove these two settings, the image will more or less look like sitting inside a button, suggesting clickability. But another way to achieve that is to make the image itself button-like, and in that case, it is probably better to remove the default features (as a button inside a button would look odd).